# git receive-pack stops with 0000

Tags: git, trac, opensuse

I'm very new to git and currently trie to setup an environment with gitolite and trac on opensuse.

I managed to migrate an old svn repository with the scripts from http://john.albin.net/git/git-svn-migrate.

Now I'm stuck with the trac/git-integration since the git-receive-pack command doesn't behave as expected.

When performing the below command, it hangs after printing 0000 and I got to press CTRL+C to return.

```
$ git-receive-pack .
0072c0b863c86da4bb75caa8cb5b6cd46604096b84e9 refs/heads/master report-status delete-refs side-band-64k ofs-delta
0046c0b863c86da4bb75caa8cb5b6cd46604096b84e9 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
0048c0b863c86da4bb75caa8cb5b6cd46604096b84e9 refs/remotes/origin/master
0000
```

I tried to execute the command on the fresh migrated repository, on the gitolite admin repository and on a local clone on my windows client with git on cygwin. In all cases I'm stuck with the above behaviour.

receive-pack returns some probably correct lines, followed by 0000 and hangs.

Does anyone have an idea what here is going on?

All comments on git-receive-pack focus on certificate or path errors - and they all work completely or not. But in my case it returns a few lines and stops???

Why do I ask this?

My trac installation return the following error:

```
Trac[git_fs] ERROR: GitError: Could not retrieve GIT version (tried to execute/parse '/usr/bin/git-receive-pack --version' but got ValueError('need more than 0 values to unpack',))
```

Cloning, pulling and pushing seems to work, but I've had another error with an 'ä' in a tag name in svn which caused problems with gitolite after svn-to-git-migration. So I thought there might by another issue with git.

Comment: Why are you running `git-receive-pack` manually? Most `git` gurus don't even do that - it's not designed for interactive use and expects a certain protocol to be followed on it's input (thus the "hang" - it's waiting for input). What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the [man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-receive-pack)

> Invoked by [`git send-pack`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-pack) and updates the repository with the information fed from the remote end.
>
> **This command is usually not invoked directly by the end user**.
> The UI for the protocol is on the git send-pack side, and the program pair is meant to be used to push updates to remote repository

So don't spend too much time testing *that* command. Check if you can clone/push/pull your repos.

Comment: As mentioned at the beginning I'm trying to configure trac (1.0beta1) to work with git. The git integration fails with the following log output: "2012-08-14 21:47:44,294 Trac[git_fs] ERROR: GitError: Could not retrieve GIT version (tried to execute/parse '/usr/bin/git-receive-pack --version' but got ValueError('need more than 0 values to unpack',))" Thats why I'm trying to figure out whats wrong with git-receive-pack...

Comment: @user1388903 I don't think there is anything wrong with `git-receive-pack`: you need to double check http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracGit, and also all the settings you put in the `trac.ini` git section (http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/0.13/TracIni#git-section)

Answer (score 0):

Your research have taken you in a wrong direction. The problem is how openSUSE builds and installs Git, and the way it links the executables - just follow this chain:

1. /usr/bin/git -> ../lib/git/git-add
2. /usr/lib/git/git-add -> git
3. /usr/lib/git/git -> ../../bin/git-receive-pack

As Trac originally made the `[git] git_bin` a `PathOption`, Trac would actually resolve the path including links and actually execute `/usr/bin/git-receive-pack --version`. The problem is of course that `git-receive-pack` does not support a `--version` argument and therefore fails.

This has been changed in recent Trac version, see http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/10997

The patch to fix it for older Trac and plugin versions is trivial (`PathOption` -> `Option`).