# Git-receive-pack not found on Windows

Tags: git, github

I've tried many things before creating this topic. Since, many seem to have this problem. So here's the thing. I simply can't push to git-hub. I know what you might be thinking, that I haven't added the bin directory to my PATH. But, I have, so before you mark this as a duplicate, please consider that I've looked at these:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186040/git-receive-pack-stops-with-0000
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225291/git-upload-pack-command-not-found-how-to-fix-this-correctly
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323268/git-upload-pack-not-found
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777797/git-push-error-git-receive-pack
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483722/git-receive-pack-command-not-found-in-windows
```

I've even downloaded the github for windows app, and it still gives me the same error. So, what do you do, when you get this error, on a windows machine, I', running Git 1.8.1. This is the error:

```
https://github.com/random12345@gmail.com/random.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

**EDIT 1:**
Not showing my real email, I'm just showing you the gist of the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
https://github.com/random12345@gmail.com/random.git
```

That URL seems strange. Remember, that your username isn't your email address. Did you use the exact URL which is shown in the Github web interface?

Comment: not the real thing, no. But yes, the username is the email address.

Comment: thanks, I did not know that the username is not the e-mail, because I was able to log in.

Comment: You can't believe how happy you've made me. I can't believe the solutions was that simple.